# What species is this lizard?

Tags: species-identification, herpetology

[image: https://i.imgur.com/SXv2OzR.jpg]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GdbuS.jpg]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABY52.jpg]

A small green lizard (20 cm in size). It was found in the direct neighboorhood of a house, in a small village in the Hungarian hills south of the Balaton lake. It was found in the middle of the day.

Our first guess would be [*Lacerta viridis*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_green_lizard). Is this correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the picture and the official distribution it looks to be as you said a `Lacerta viridis`.

Some references and distribution here:

- https://www.iucnredlist.org/species/61530/12507156
- https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Lacerta_viridis
- http://reptile-database.reptarium.cz/species?genus=Lacerta&species=viridis

In Western Europe we have a brother specie `Lacerta bilineata`.

Example in Geneva:

[image: WesternGreenLizard]

The distribution maps shows that `Lacerta viridis` is mainly present in Easter Europe (including Hungary) and `Lacerta bilineata` is present in the Western Europe.

Both species are similar and the male get the throat blue generally during the breeding season.

[This site](http://www.sauria.org.uk/cap_breed/animals/viridis.htm) have also a description of the specie.

Comment: I think it's the biggest lizard locally in most places, i.e. in France it's the biggest lizard i have seen, up to 40cm. the ones with the most blue are the best, they vary a lot.